# Socket.io Android NullPointerException and cannot find the cause

Tags: java, android, socket.io

I'm working on an android/ios app game working with the [socket.io java client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) and a node.js backend also working with socket.io. On the ios app, everything works well, but my analytics tool shows me that in android there are a lot of users facing a fatal exception. Here it is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
   at io.socket.client.Socket.onevent(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.client.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.client.Socket.open(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.client.Socket$2$2.call(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.on(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.client.Manager.emitAll(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.client.Manager.reconnection(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.client.Manager$7.call(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.on(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.parser.Parser$Decoder.add(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.client.Manager.emitAll(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.client.Manager.reconnection(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.client.Manager$2.call(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.on(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.open(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.open(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.on(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onError(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.pause(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling$2.call(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.parser.Parser.encodePacket(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.pause(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.pause(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$5$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I'm using version 1.7.4 on node.js backend, version 0.9.0 of the [socket.io java client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java). I tried many things getting rid of this exception, but nothing seems to work like using this library in a singleton or in a service.

Is there anyone facing this problem too?

If you need more code examples of the project or want to have a look on the app (it's in the stores), let me know.

Here is the example code from the android app:

```
public class SocketManager {

    private static SocketManager instance;
    private Socket socket;

    public static SocketManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new SocketManager();
        return instance;
    }

    private SocketManager() {
        try {
            IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
            options.forceNew = true;

            socket = IO.socket(ApiConstants.Routes.URL, options);

            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "connected");

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
                array.put(Prefs.getAuthToken());
                array.put(Prefs.getGroupId());
                socket.emit("updateUserSocket", array);
            });

            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "disconnected");
            });

            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_RECONNECT, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "reconnected");
            });

            socket.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "error");
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.USER_UPDATED, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "user updated");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.USER_UPDATED);
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.USER_SELF_REMOVED, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "user self removed");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.USER_SELF_REMOVED);
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.START_GAME, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "start game");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.START_GAME);
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.START_VOTING, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "start voting");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.START_VOTING);
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.GROUP_DELETED, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "group deleted");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.GROUP_DELETED);
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.UPDATE_GROUP, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "update group");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.UPDATE_GROUP);
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.GAME_P1, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "game p1");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.GAME_P1);
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.GAME_P2, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "game p2");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.GAME_P2);
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.GAME_P3, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "game p3");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.GAME_P3);
            });

            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.GAME_P4, (dataArray) -> {
                Log.e("SocketManager", "game p4");
                sendBroadcast(Constants.SocketEvents.GAME_P4);
            });
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void sendBroadcast(String event) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(event);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyApp.getContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public void connect() {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.connect();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is android app  native ?

Comment: Jep, all native

Comment: can you share the code ,at which point it shows exception

Comment: Looks like the exception is coming from the library itself. But I'll update my question to show you the code I'm using for socket.io in my android app.

Comment: at io.socket.client.Socket.onevent(Unknown Source)
there might be one parameter which is unknown .

Comment: I updated my question, have a look @VivekPatel

Comment: is your socket gets connected ?

Comment: Yes. For most of the users everything works well. Just a few of them are facing this problem. Why are people downvoting my question? Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: We are also facing the same problem. How did you manage to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source code of the library, I have come to the conclusion that the code that throws the exception is this:

```
    if (this.connected) {
        if (args.isEmpty()) return;
        String event = args.remove(0).toString();  // HERE
        super.emit(event, args.toArray());
    } else {
        this.receiveBuffer.add(args);
    }
```

Based on the context, it looks the client has received a JSON array whose first element is a `null`.  So maybe the problem is a result of this code:

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put(Prefs.getAuthToken());
    array.put(Prefs.getGroupId());
    socket.emit("updateUserSocket", array);
```

running with `null` auth token.

---

But there is something fishy about this.  The stacktrace clearly shows that Socket.open is calling Socket.connect.  But this is not possible according to the source code for version 0.9.0 of the client library.  See for yourself:

- https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java/blob/socket.io-client-0.9.0/src/main/java/io/socket/client/Socket.java   lines 130 through 150.

Are you sure you are using that version?

Here's a possibility: while you compiled against version 0.9.0, perhaps some of your users are somehow using a version that doesn't match the published source code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, I'm sure that I'm using version 0.9.0 and I know that there are some users using an older version of the app where the version of the library was another, but in my analytics tool I can clearly see that the users facing this problem are using the latest version of the app. I will try making sure that Prefs.getAuthToken() not returning null now.

Comment: So how do you explain the inconsistency between the stacktrace and source code?

Comment: I have no idea why this is happening. Also just about 10% of the users are having this problem. In build.gradle: implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.9.0')

Comment: I'm not asking for an explanation of how it happens.  I am questioning that it happens at all.  Or possibly the accuracy of the stacktrace you showed us.

Comment: If I knew the reason why this is happening I could fix this, but I don't. The stacktrace that I showed you is from Crashlytics. My problem with finding the reason for that exception is that I cannot reproduce it, neither with the emulator nor a real device.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but the probable reason is that your server disconnects (restarts?) after you change preferences. I made a workaround in order to get rid of similar error like below.

```
socket.emit("updateUserSocket", array);
            socket.disconnect();
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    socket.connect();
                }
            }, 500);
```

If you know specific event affected by this preference change, you might disable and restart the event handler. In your case it might be:

```
socket.off(Constants.SocketEvents.USER_UPDATED, yourEmitterListener);
socket.emit("updateUserSocket", array);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            socket.on(Constants.SocketEvents.USER_UPDATED, yourEmitterListener);
        }
    }, 500);
```